# Insert a default row into a combobox that is bound to a datatable?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, combobox, datatable

On a winform there is a combobox that derives its information from a datatable.  The datatable draws from a database list.

```
this.cboList.DataSource = pullData();
this.cboList.DisplayMember = "fieldA";
```

Once the DataSource is set I am not able to insert a default row (ie *) as the first item in the combobox.

I tried this:

```
this.cboList.Items.Insert(0,"*");
```

Is there a way to insert in the combobox after the datasource is set or should this be done in the datatable?

**UPDATE1:**

The solution looks something like this:

```
 var list = mydt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>(fieldName)).ToList();
 list.Insert(0, "*");
```

Where mydt is a populated datatable and fieldName is a variable holding the database field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify your data at the source just to make your UI work. Instead, perhaps extract your column into a list that you can modify before attaching it to the combo box.

```
var list = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("fieldA")).ToList();
list.Insert(0, "*");
this.cboList.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: I am getting a InvalidCastException -> where would I convert/cast a System.Double to System.String in the code you show?

Comment: @John - If your column is a double, you would modify it like this `.Select(row => row.Field<double>("fieldA").ToString("0.00")).ToList();`, where "0.00" is the format for your numbers (format can be omitted or altered).

Answer (score 0):

If a "Select None", or "*" is a valid select option it needs to come from the binding source object.  I have done this in the past by adding a default record to a collection before binding it to a combo box.